# Error when bundling one year old Rails app on new machine w latest Ruby (2.4.1) + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rubygems, upgrade

I just tried to revive an old Rails app of mine, created July 2016.

When bundling on my new machine with fresh installs of Ruby and Rails I got this error, because `json` is now included into rails, and not needed in the Gemfile anymore:

```
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

If I remove the gem from the Gemfile.lock (edit: this is probably very stupid, but there was no mention of json in the Gemfile, why i looked into the Gemfile.lock), I get `Unfortunately, an unexpected error occurred, and Bundler cannot continue.` on bundle install:

````
The git source `git://github.com/flori/json.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
The git source `git://github.com/capistrano/rbenv.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
Fetching git://github.com/flori/json.git
The git source `git://github.com/flori/json.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
The git source `git://github.com/capistrano/rbenv.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
--- ERROR REPORT TEMPLATE -------------------------------------------------------
# Error Report

## Questions

Please fill out answers to these questions, it'll help us figure out
why things are going wrong.

- **What did you do?**

  I ran the command `/home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/bundle install`

- **What did you expect to happen?**

  I expected Bundler to...

- **What happened instead?**

  Instead, what happened was...

- **Have you tried any solutions posted on similar issues in our issue tracker, stack overflow, or google?**

  I tried...

- **Have you read our issues document, https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/doc/contributing/ISSUES.md?**

  ...

## Backtrace

```
ArgumentError: Invalid source: nil
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/source_list.rb:107:in `source_list_for'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/source_list.rb:56:in `get'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:746:in `block in converge_locked_specs'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/forwardable.rb:229:in `each'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/forwardable.rb:229:in `each'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:743:in `converge_locked_specs'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:228:in `resolve'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:147:in `resolve_remotely!'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:226:in `resolve_if_need'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:78:in `run'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:24:in `install'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:68:in `run'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:191:in `block in install'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/settings.rb:92:in `temporary'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:190:in `install'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:22:in `dispatch'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:13:in `start'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

## Environment

```
Bundler   1.15.3
Rubygems  2.6.11
Ruby      2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
GEM_HOME  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
GEM_PATH  /home/howard/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0:/home/howard/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
Git       2.7.4
Platform  x86_64-linux
OpenSSL   OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

## Bundler settings

```
without
  Set for your local app (/home/howard/Downloads/telefon/code/.bundle/config): "development:test"
```

## Gemfile

### Gemfile

```ruby
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.1'
gem 'json', github: 'flori/json', branch: 'v1.8'

# Add this if you're using rbenv
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', github: "capistrano/rbenv"

gem "browser"

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

### Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/capistrano/rbenv.git
  revision: e056efc0c361cc15b76ff961d6c5f65ed5e2c57e
  specs:
    capistrano-rbenv (2.0.4)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:'
    actionmailer (4.2.6)
      actionpack (= 4.2.6)
      actionview (= 4.2.6)
      activejob (= 4.2.6)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.6)
      actionview (= 4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.6)
      activemodel (= 4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.6)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.3)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    browser (2.1.0)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (9.0.5)
    capistrano (3.1.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capistrano-bundler (1.1.4)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-rails (1.1.7)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.1.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
    minitest (5.9.0)
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (3.1.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.8)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
      pkg-config (~> 1.1.7)
    pkg-config (1.1.7)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.6)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.6)
      actionpack (= 4.2.6)
      actionview (= 4.2.6)
      activejob (= 4.2.6)
      activemodel (= 4.2.6)
      activerecord (= 4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.6)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.2.6)
      actionpack (= 4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (11.2.2)
    rdoc (4.2.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.4.22)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    spring (1.7.1)
    sprockets (3.6.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.0.4)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.11)
    sshkit (1.11.1)
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.5)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.0.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (2.3.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  browser
  byebug
  capistrano (~> 3.1.0)
  capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1.2)
  capistrano-rails (~> 1.1.1)
  capistrano-rbenv!
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  rails (= 4.2.6)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  sqlite3
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.12.5
```

--- TEMPLATE END ----------------------------------------------------------------

Unfortunately, an unexpected error occurred, and Bundler cannot continue.

First, try this link to see if there are any existing issue reports for this error:
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/search?q=Invalid+source++nil&type=Issues

If there aren't any reports for this error yet, please create copy and paste the report template above into a new issue. Don't forget to anonymize any private data! The new issue form is located at:
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/new
````

Does anybody know what i could try to get out of this situation?

Thanks

Comment: So, in case anybody finds this via Google and similar error messages, i could not figure it out. I copied the `views` , `controllers`, `routes.rb` into a freshly created rails app and added the gems i used into the Gemfile, then it started w/o problems. Thanks gentlemen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to remove a gem you should remove it from your `Gemfile`, not `Gemfile.lock`.

In your `Gemfile`: `gem 'json', github: 'flori/json', branch: 'v1.8'`

`bundler` creates `Gemfile.lock` for you after it resolves your dependencies during `bundle install`, based on whatever's in your `Gemfile`. `Gemfile.lock` also specifies gems that are not in your `Gemfile` but are dependencies of gems that are. Editing it manually is almost guaranteed to cause you problems and fix nothing.

But you probably don't need to remove it at all. Right now you're locked onto a version of `json` that `bundler`'s having trouble resolving. You should delete `Gemfile.lock` and let `bundler` generate a brand new one.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, the thing is, in the Gemfile, there is nothing about a json gem

Comment: @Howard from your `Gemfile`: `gem 'json', github: 'flori/json', branch: 'v1.8'`. But I would try using `bundle exec` first if you haven't already, just to be sure

Comment: @Howard I think the problem could be that your Rails version in the `Gemfile` is `4.2.6`, and if you got a new machine and did `gem install rails` then that's probably `5.1.x`, so doing `$ rails <command>` will be using `5.1.x` and there might be conflicts. If you do `bundle exec rails <command>` it should use the bundled `4.2.6`

Comment: Yes that with the 5.1. is true. Sorry i got confused with that line in the Gemfile bc i copied the project into multiple folders to try out diff. Gemfile&Gemfile.lock configs. Now i deleted all of them and try to start from scratch w the zip archive from 2016. If in unzip it and run bundle install: `An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.` ... what whas my initial issue why i altered the Gemfiles in the first place. What could i do? Thanks a lot for your help, i very appreciate it

Comment: Now i changed the rails version in the Gemfile to `5.1.2` and hoped that might maybe help when i do a `bundle install`, but: `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0) was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0)

    rails (= 5.1.2) was resolved to 5.1.2, which depends on
      railties (= 5.1.2)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)

    web-console (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.3.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0)
`

Comment: No, I wouldn't do that. Restore the entire `Gemfile`, then `$ rm Gemfile.lock` and `bundle install`. You want to start with your original `Gemfile` and no `Gemfile.lock`, and let `bundler` create a brand new `Gemfile.lock` from scratch. Hopefully that works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150234/discussion-between-m-simon-borg-and-howard).